# Would or Could, in a list of questions, is the first verb always the correct choice?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, modal-verbs, syllepsis

Here is an example of what I am wondering about:

> I wonder why or how someone could kill a person.

In this sentence we have two questions, *why* and *how*. They both require different supporting words: *would* and *could*. Here I have chosen *could*, but *would* also sounds fine.

Which is correct? Does the order of *why* and *how* in my sentence matter? Finally, what is the name for *why* and *how* in this sentence?

Edit: I think this is a Syllepsis, and thus correct.

Comment: I am new to the site, if I used a wrong tag or missed a question along these lines, just let me know.

Comment: It seems to me that "why" goes with "would" and "how" with "could" (not the other way round as you wrote), so by choosing "could" you've chosen the *second* choice.

Comment: @ShereevatsaR hehe, oops!

Comment: Would you? Could you? /
in a car? /
Eat them! Eat them! /
Here they are.

Comment: @nohat nice, very nice.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to "is the first verb always the correct choice?" is **No**. The reason is the following:

If you choose "I wonder why and how someone **could** kill a person.", you're saying the same as "I wonder why someone could kill a person and how someone could kill a person." You don't mean that.

And if you choose "I wonder why and how someone **would** kill a person.", you're saying the same as "I wonder why someone would kill a person and how someone would kill a person." You don't mean exactly that either.

The only solution that I can think of is to rebuild the sentence, otherwise you won't be expressing what you mean clearly. Something like:

**I wonder why someone would kill a person and also how someone could do it.**

Answer (score 0):

Either is correct, depending on the intended meaning.

---

> 1) I wonder why or how someone could kill a person.

This is asking two questions, of course. The first is: "I wonder why someone could kill a person.". This is a somewhat odd question if taken literally. The appropriate (though rather trite) response might be "Because we are all physical beings and are thus capable of killing."

The second question is: "I wonder how someone could kill a person.". To this, a valid response might be, "With the use of a weapon such as a gun or knife, or one of various other means.".

> 2) I wonder why or how someone would kill a person.

Again, taking the first question: "I wonder why someone would kill a person.". To this, a valid response might be, "Perhaps because that person is an enemy in war.".

The second question being, of course: "I wonder how someone would kill a person." This is quite similar to the second question of version 1, though with a subtle difference. It implies a specific intention that someone would kill another person, or similarly, what would be a *likely* means of killing.

---

Finally, the order of *why* and *how* is not really a matter of grammar, so either way round is acceptable. However, I would tend to put *how* first as it is the more direct/superficial interrogative.

Answer (score 0):

"Would" infers motive (love, money, jealousy, etc.), whereas "could" infers method (with a gun, knife, radiation poisoning, etc.). Noldorin answered this in a more detailed manner, however.

Edit: In my opinion, there isn't a "correct" use here -- it depends on what you mean. "Could" and "would" are two entirely separate questions.

Comment: By "infers" you mean "implies". (The words imply, *we* infer.)

Comment: Notice that he's not asking whether he should use "could" or "would". He's actually asking how to combine the meaning of both in the same sentence: "In this sentence we have two questions, why and how. They both require different supporting words: would and could. "

Comment: @Shreevatsar, you're right -- I confused myself by thinking in terms of "You infer motive by using would"

Comment: @Bruno, I see your point. However, I can't help but feel that the original question, if your interpretation is correct, does not communicate that in a clear manner.